# How do I create a footer that will stick to the bottom of the screen regardless of the container height?

Tags: html, css, containers, footer

I can't seem to figure this out.  I have a footer that I want to display at the bottom of the page regardless of the height of the container and regardless of the screen size.  It seems that on some larger screens the background scrolls all the way to the bottom of the page and the footer is in the middle and on regular 13 inch 17 inch screens it's ok.

CSS:

```
#container {
background-color: #ffffff;
min-height: 320px;
margin: 100px auto;
width: 960px;
max-width: 100%;
}
#footer {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
position:absolute;
margin-top: 140px;
}
```

Comment: You need this http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/sticky-footer.html

Looks like they're setting

```
min-height: 100%
height: auto !important
```

on the main content section, then adding the footer element after it.

Comment: Be sure to set `html, body { min-height: 100%; }` as well.